# Accessing SQL output in coding

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL output like

```
TotalLeave    Status
----------    ------
    3        PaidLeave
    5        MedicalLave
```

and I need to show this value in my label controls like,

```
lblMedicalLeave.text = 5
lblPaidLeave.text    = 3
```

for this I just created objects for my dataset in my code like,

```
StaffAttendanceStatusTableAdapters.StaffTypesTableAdapter staffAttendanceStatus = 
                  new StaffAttendanceStatusTableAdapters.StaffTypesTableAdapter();
StaffAttendanceStatus.StaffTypesDataTable StaffDataTable = 
               staffAttendanceStatus.GetDataStaffAttendanceStatus(staff.StaffId);

        if (StaffDataTable[0] != null)
        {
            StaffAttendanceStatus.StaffTypesRow StaffRow = StaffDataTable[0];

            lblTotalMedicalLeave.Text = StaffRow.TotalLeave.ToString();
            lblTotalPaidLeave.Text = StaffRow.TotalLeave.ToString();
        }
```

its showing the same value(3), is it possible to get the TotalLeave value for corresponding Status? can anyone help me here

Comment: You are accessing the same row both times. Use StaffDataTable[1] to access the second row. Anyway you should check if there is a result before access any values!

Comment: exactly, I understood my mistake, Y don't u post this in answer session, so that I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the *same row both times*. Use **StaffDataTable[1]** to access the second row. Anyway you should check if there is a result before access any values!

```
using StaffAttendanceStatusTableAdapters;
....


StaffTypesTableAdapter staffAttendanceStatus = new StaffTypesTableAdapter();
StaffAttendanceStatus.StaffTypesDataTable StaffDataTable = 
           staffAttendanceStatus.GetDataStaffAttendanceStatus(staff.StaffId);

if (StaffDataTable != null && StaffDataTable.Count > 1)
{
    lblTotalMedicalLeave.Text = StaffDataTable[0].TotalLeave.ToString();
    lblTotalPaidLeave.Text = StaffDataTable[1].TotalLeave.ToString();
}
```

hth

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to get TotalLeave from two rows, you need to fetch data from two rows.

```
if (StaffDataTable != null && StaffDataTable.Rows.Count > 1)
{
  StaffAttendanceStatus.StaffTypesRow StaffRow1 = StaffDataTable[0];
  StaffAttendanceStatus.StaffTypesRow StaffRow2 = StaffDataTable[1];

  lblTotalMedicalLeave.Text = StaffRow1.TotalLeave.ToString();
  lblTotalPaidLeave.Text = StaffRow2.TotalLeave.ToString();
}
```

if there is no order of PaidLeave and MedicalLave status, just check row.Status and assign total value to corresponding label